# Can we apply the symmetric difference operation on two multisets?

Tags: multisets

I was just reading about multisets and operations on them. I didn't find mention of applying symmetric difference on multisets. Can we apply the operation on multisets like we can over sets? I decomposed the symmetric difference formula to the elementary one which is:- $ P \cup Q - P \cap Q $ given:-

$$ P = \{a,a,a,b,b,c,d,d,e \} $$ and
$$ Q = \{a, a, b, b, b, c, c, d, d, f \} $$.

and the result was $ \{a,b,c,e,f \} $. Is this correct? I am still confused how and if it applies to multiset.

Comment: You can define this operation, sure, why not?